# How can I get a python function that uses Zbar to work in AWS lambda?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have built the following qr reader function following some tutorials on how to do this in python. The main library that performs the job is Zbar (or PyZbar or simmilar derivations). I have had the function up and running in my computer and it seems to work just fine.

Now I want to build a small app with it, and since I want to keep things separate I want the qr decoder function to work on demand from an AWS lambda. The idea is, someone takes a picture of a QR code with their app, uploads the picture (to an S3 bucket) and the Lambda function reacts on this upload, reads the code and returns the data from the QR code.

I have been doing my research, being new to AWS lambda myself, and have been able to figure out that the function needs to be uploaded with the dependencies if they are not preinstalled on AWS. I have been able to upload them following this video's instructions. However when I give the function a test run, it throws an error.

I am starting to wonder whether it is actually possible to have a QR reader built into a Lambda function... Any help on this/point to other ways to do this/preexisting services to do this?

Code of my function:

```
def scan_qr(image):
    # USAGE
    # python barcode_scanner_image.py --image barcode_example.png

    # import the necessary packages
    from pyzbar import pyzbar
    import argparse
    import cv2
    import pandas as pd

    # construct the argument parser and parse the arguments
    args=image

    # load the input image
    image = cv2.imread(args)

    # find the barcodes in the image and decode each of the barcodes
    barcodes = pyzbar.decode(image)

    # loop over the detected barcodes
    for barcode in barcodes:
        # extract the bounding box location of the barcode and draw the
        # bounding box surrounding the barcode on the image
        (x, y, w, h) = barcode.rect
        cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 0, 255), 2)

        # the barcode data is a bytes object so if we want to draw it on
        # our output image we need to convert it to a string first
        barcodeData = barcode.data.decode("utf-8")
        barcodeType = barcode.type

        # print the barcode type and data to the terminal
        your_list = pd.DataFrame(
        {'type': [barcodeType],
        'url': [barcodeData]
        })
        your_list = your_list[your_list.type=='QRCODE']

        return(your_list)
```

Comment: How did you package the Python dependencies? What does the folder structure look like?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how you packaged the lib, so here's small guide on lambda packaging.

As a rule of thumb, directory structure of a packaged lib for python lambda should be like:

```
lib_name |
         |-- python |
                    |-- (all of lib files here)
```

You can install third-party library into arbitrary dir using `pip install -t (path)`.

So if you're preparing lambda package on Unix/Linux system, it will look something like this:

```
mkdir -p lib_name/python
pip install lib_name -t lib_name/python
```

Sometimes people get errors when uploading packages zipped on Windows systems (due to different file permissions models), so I do recommend doing it on Unix/Linux systems if available.

Answer (score 0):

Zbar has native dependencies.
The new Lambda feature allows you to build your own docker image. So you can build zbar into the image.